# How to modify and save already opened excel file

Tags: python

I have python script which use data from `.xlsx` file and also write to this file. I'm looking for sollution how to proceed script and keep open `.xlsx` file.

description:

1. User have open `data.xlsx`
2. start python script, which read, write and save data to `data.xlsx`
3. after script finish user see updated `data.xlsx`

```
import openpyxl
import datetime

email_list_path = "d:\\test folder\\data.xlsx"

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(email_list_path)

seznam_adres = wb["mailing list"]

for i in range(2, 5 + 1):

    verze_emailu = seznam_adres.cell(row=i, column=6).value

    cas = datetime.datetime.now()
    seznam_adres.cell(row=i, column=5).value = cas.strftime('%x %X')

wb.save('email_list.xlsx')
```

I'm useing openpyxl to manage .xlsx file and if I save it `wb.save('data.xlsx')` it return error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\\test folder\\Send_email.py", line 141, in \<module\>
> wb.save('email_list.xlsx')
> 
> File "D:\\test folder\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\openpyxl\\workbook\\workbook.py", line 386, in save
> save_workbook(self, filename)
> 
> File "D:\\test folder\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\openpyxl\\writer\\excel.py", line 291, in save_workbook
> archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
> 
> File "C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\lib\\zipfile.py", line 1249, in __init__
> self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
> PermissionError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied: 'email_list.xlsx'
```

Comment: You cant do that, use vba or office script isntead

Comment: I'm sorry for wrong destription. File 'email_list.xlsx' == 'data.xlsx' I mixed old and new veesion of scrip and error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` library to see and edit your excel file. It is much easier to read data and modify your data with `pandas`

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('YOUR_PATH')
""" 
modify your data 
"""
# export your data as an excel file
data.to_excel('email_list.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

you got Permission denied to write in the email_list.xlsx, first check your access to write in this path, then, for  modify already opened excel file:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('path/file.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
sheet['A1'] = 'Your Value'
wb.save('path/file.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

this script that modifies the value in cell A1 and saves the changes to an Excel file